# Custom TabControl for CloseableTabs

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, tabcontrol, itemssource

There are a few solutions here for Closeable tabs but they all depend on the owner of the collection to provide the closing functionality.

I thought perhaps it would be possible by creating a Custom `TabControl` and `TabItem` that this could be done in the CodeBehind.

The idea would be to somehow alert the `TabControl` from the `TabItem` that the close button has been pressed (perhaps with a bubbling event or something, please suggest) and then remove that particular items wrapped in that `TabItem` from the `ItemsSource`.

Problem is I'm not sure how or even if this is possible. Can you somehow remove items from a collection set as `ItemsSource` in a `TabControl`? Could we perhaps set a new DP sow we have full control over the Collection and just set that as `ItemsSource` in Code Behind.

Anyone done this or has any ideas hwo to do this. Is it even possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Even if that's technically possible, I'd advise sticking to M-V-VM. Let the owner of the collection i.e. the ViewModel control adding/deleting items from the collection. 
Let the View be thin and sync with the VM's collection via data-binding. This keeps the Views from getting complex and eliminates the GUI which is a deterrent to testability.

You should find that as the path of least WPF resistance.

Comment: See Josh Smith's MVVM MSDN article for an illustration of how closeable tabs can be implemented using MVVM.

Comment: Well some you could see this as a problem for the GUI to handle and not the ViewModel. It is about presenting data so I don't see it necceserily breaking MVVM, like how you can have an expander and such. But of course that doesn't effect behind the scenes collections.

Answer (score 1):

This came up in our application, so I figured I would post my solution.  ClosableTabControl closes any tab by removing the item from the bound ItemsSource.  This is partially scraped from other solutions ([Szymon Kobalczyk](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/04/08/closeabletabitem.aspx) et al.).

[image: Example style for ClosableTabControl]

ClosableTabControl.cs:

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(ClosableTabItem))]
public class ClosableTabControl : TabControl
{
    static ClosableTabControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabControl)));

        CloseTabCommand = new RoutedCommand();
    }

    public ClosableTabControl()
        : base()
    {
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CloseTabCommand, CloseTabCommand_Execute));
    }

    public static ICommand CloseTabCommand { get; private set; }

    private void CloseTabCommand_Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Parameter == null || !(args.Parameter is ClosableTabItem))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter must be of type ClosableTabItem");

        var item = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer((ClosableTabItem)args.Parameter);
        if (item == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Item not in collection");

        IEditableCollectionView view = this.Items;
        if (!view.CanRemove)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Read-only collection");

        view.Remove(item);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ClosableTabItem();
    }
}
```

ClosableTabItem.cs:

```
public class ClosableTabItem : TabItem
{
    static ClosableTabItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ClosableTabItem)));
    }
}
```

Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ClosableTabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" />

<Style x:Key="TabItemFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="3,3,3,1"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EAF6FD" Offset="0.15"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#D9F0FC" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BEE6FD" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#A7D9F5" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedBackground" Color="#F9F9F9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBorderBrush" Color="#3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBackground" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFC9C7BA"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ClosableTabItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonOverBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFA" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE0E0E3" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE0E0E2" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F8F8" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF969696"/>
        <Style x:Key="CloseableTabItemButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" Opacity="0" />
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonOverBackground}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Chrome" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedBackground}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClosableTabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" >
                        <DockPanel x:Name="ContentPanel">
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Close" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style="{DynamicResource CloseableTabItemButtonStyle}" ToolTip="Close" Command="{x:Static local:ClosableTabControl.CloseTabCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ClosableTabItem}}}">
                                <Path x:Name="Path" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="#FF333333" Fill="#FF969696" Data="F1 M 2.28484e-007,1.33331L 1.33333,0L 4.00001,2.66669L 6.66667,6.10352e-005L 8,1.33331L 5.33334,4L 8,6.66669L 6.66667,8L 4,5.33331L 1.33333,8L 1.086e-007,6.66669L 2.66667,4L 2.28484e-007,1.33331 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Button>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" SourceName="PART_Close" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Path" Value="#FFB83C3D"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" SourceName="PART_Close" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Path" Value="#FF9D3838"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectedBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBorderBrush}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```